# Possible stack corruption in C

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

While trying to pass an argument to a function; the function receives the wrong value thus creating a segmentation fault while trying to use that value

argc and argv in the main function are corrupted before the program even starts
[image: GDB output]

main.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#include "util/BasicTypes.h"
#include "util/IncludeOpengl.h"
#include "util/Vec2.h"
#include "util/Vec3.h"
#include "util/Vec4.h"
#include "util/Vector.h"


#if !(defined(__linux__) || defined(_WIN64))
    STATIC_ASSERT(false, unsupported_system)
#endif


i32 main(i32 argc, ch8** argv) {
    //u32 a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    //u32* b = a;
    u32 i;

    Vector v;
    init_Vector(&v, sizeof(u32));
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%i\n", i);
        Vector_append(&v, &i);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < Vector_getSize(&v); i++) {
        printf("%i\n", Vector_get(&v, i));
    }

    destruct_Vector(&v);

    return 0;
}
```

vector.c file where i define the vector functions:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_C
#define VECTOR_C


#include "../util/Vector.h"


#include "../util/BasicTypes.h"
#include "../util/Assert.h"


void init_Vector(Vector* self, u32 elementSize) {
    self->elementSize = elementSize;
    self->elements = NULL;
    self->elementCount = 0;
}
void destruct_Vector(Vector* self) {
    if (self->elements) {
        heapFree(self->elements);
    }
}

void Vector_append(Vector* self, void* element) {
    if (self->elements) {
        self->elements = heapRealloc(self->elements, self->elementCount + 1);
        memcpy(((byte*)self->elements) + (self->elementCount) * self->elementSize, element, self->elementSize);
        self->elementCount += 1;
        return;
    }
    else {
        self->elements = heapAlloc((usize)self->elementSize);
        memcpy(self->elements, element, self->elementSize);
        self->elementCount += 1;
        return;
    }
}
void Vector_remove(Vector* self, u32 id) {
    if (id < self->elementCount) {
        void* temp = self->elements;
        self->elements = heapAlloc((self->elementCount - 1) * self->elementSize);
        memcpy(self->elements, temp, id * self->elementSize);
        memcpy(((byte*)self->elements) + id * self->elementSize, ((byte*)temp) + (id + 1) * self->elementSize, (self->elementCount - id - 1) * self->elementSize);
        self->elementCount -= 1;
    }
    else {
        ASSERT(false, "(Vector_remove) id is not in the list");
    }
}
void Vector_insert(Vector* self, void* element, u32 id) {
    if (!self->elements && !id) {
        self->elements = heapAlloc(self->elementSize);
        self->elementCount = 1;
    }
    else {
        if (id < self->elementCount + 1) {
            void* temp = self->elements;
            self->elements = heapAlloc((self->elementCount - 1) * self->elementSize);
            memcpy(self->elements, temp, id * self->elementSize);
            memcpy(((byte*)self->elements) + (id + 1) * self->elementSize, ((byte*)temp) + (id) * self->elementSize, (self->elementCount - id - 1) * self->elementSize);
            memcpy(((byte*)self->elements), ((byte*)temp), self->elementSize);
            self->elementCount += 1;
        }
        else {
            ASSERT(false, "(Vector_insert) id is too far");
        }
    }
}
void* Vector_get(Vector* self, u32 id) {
    return ((byte*)self->elements) + id * self->elementSize;
}
u32 Vector_getSize(Vector* self) {
    return self->elementCount;
}


#endif // VECTOR_C
```

vector.h file the header file for vector.c:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H


#include "../util/BasicTypes.h"


typedef struct Vector {
    void* elements;
    u32 elementSize;
    u32 elementCount;
} Vector;


void init_Vector(Vector* self, u32 elementSize);
void destruct_Vector(Vector* self);

void Vector_append(Vector* self, void* element);
void Vector_remove(Vector* self, u32 id);
void Vector_insert(Vector* self, void* element, u32 id);
void* Vector_get(Vector* self, u32 id);
u32 Vector_getSize(Vector* self);


#endif // VECTOR_H
```

basictypes.h file where i define some aliases:

```
#ifndef BASIC_TYPES_H
#define BASIC_TYPES_H


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


typedef int8_t         i8;
typedef int16_t        i16;
typedef int32_t        i32;
typedef int64_t        i64;

typedef uint8_t        u8;
typedef uint16_t       u16;
typedef uint32_t       u32;
typedef uint64_t       u64;

typedef i8             ch8;
typedef i16            ch16;
typedef i32            ch32;
typedef i64            ch64;

typedef u8             uch8;
typedef u16            uch16;
typedef u32            uch32;
typedef u64            uch64;

typedef float          f32;
typedef double         f64;
typedef long double    f128;

typedef u8             byte;
typedef size_t         usize;


#endif // BASIC_TYPES_H
```

Comment: Show the `Vector` definition and the implementation of these functions you're calling. What is the purpose of the `sizeof(u32)`? Is that the total bytes for the vector, or the size of one element, or (kinda bogus) the number of elements?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `i32` and `int` are the same on your system? And why even use those ghastly aliases?

Comment: u32 is the typedef for unsigned int, ill edit my post for the vector function

Comment: Is there a specific reason why aren't you using standard `uint32_t` types? `int` not necessarily has 32 bits. `ch8` Why not just use `char`? You have to create an [MCVE] for this forum. Please create a self-contained, compilable code that others can test. For now, check your code with static analyzers and profile with sanitizers, on linux, use `-Wall -Wextra` and `-fsanitize=address` and use Valgrind to check for memory problems.

Comment: If `main()` receives corrupted values, your startup code is defect.

Answer (score 1):

`typedef i8 ch8;` is wrong, since `int8_t` might likely expand to `signed char`, which in turn is not directly compatible with `char` unless you explicitly covert between the two types.

The format of main is not for the programmer to decide, but the compiler. gcc under strict compliance settings (`-pedantic-errors`) tells you this much:

```
error: second argument of 'main' should be 'char **' [-Wmain]
```

Besides, nobody wants to read code based on your own special type system. We have standards for a reason, so use standard C instead:

```
#include <stdint.h>

....

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
   uint32_t i;
```